# Closing gaps between polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I'm working in QGIS. I created a polygon layer of evenly spaced squares (see below). Is there any way to snap these polygons together automatically, removing all of the gaps? The only tool I'm aware of are for sliver polygons. In this case I'm dealing with actual gaps instead. I can provide the shapefile itself if necessary.

To be clear, here's what I'm trying to do: snap together all of these squares en-masse.

[image: Evenly spaced polygons]

Comment: It looks as though these were intentionally generated to have gaps. Couldn't you regenerate to *not* have gaps? That's going to be way less chaotic than buffering all the features or trying to snap them.

Comment: I will give that a shot. I used generate geography from points but had a hard time getting the measurement right so that they all touched exactly rather than overlapped. I suppose I skipped a step and should have found the right radius.

Comment: There is a create grid process in Qgis which might help with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Snap geometries to layer](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgissnapgeometries) and snap the layer to itself:

[image]

But my output wasn't uniformly sized squares so:

Calculate centroids. Manually measure the distances between two adjacent ones.  Then use this distance as width and height in [Rectangles, ovals, diamonds](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisrectanglesovalsdiamonds), with shape=Rectangle:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this.